# No puedo instalar flask-mysqldb

Tags: python-3.x

soy nuevo en stackoverflow. Mi problema llega en el terminal al instalar flask-mysqldb con pip3, el error es el siguiente:

```
julian@JAGQUBUNTU:~$ sudo pip3 install flask-mysqldb
The directory '/home/julian/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/julian/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting flask-mysqldb
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/e3/955c845efe1aacf30c8e2607470544ede36aa1044f6382c809f13e014104/Flask-MySQLdb-0.2.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.10 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-mysqldb)
Collecting mysqlclient (from flask-mysqldb)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/97/7326248ac8d5049968bf4ec708a5d3d4806e412a42e74160d7f266a3e03a/mysqlclient-1.4.6.tar.gz (85kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 3.7MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2y1fjy91/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2y1fjy91/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-2y1fjy91/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2y1fjy91/mysqlclient/
```

He encontrado una posible solución en la comunidad sobre este problema que es ejecutando en el terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev python-dev
```

Pero luego al instalar flask-mysqldb me sale otro error diferente asi que, he decidido crear una pregunta a la comunidad. Mi version de python es "Python 3.6.9" y tambien tengo instalado XAMPP.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Problema solucionado, por si alguien tiene este mismo problema, tiene que instalar desde el terminal:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev   
sudo apt install libmariadb-dev-compat
sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Con eso a mi se me acaba de solucionar el problema.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema llega en el terminal al instalar flask-mysqldb con pip, el error es el siguiente:

dice  que  tengo  que revizar :  get it  with "microsoft built  tools c++ "

y  que  visite  esa pagina  "https://virtuallstudio mirosoft.com/visual-cpp-tools/"

sera  que  tengo  que  instalar  microsoft  virtual  c++    yo  tengo  instalados desde el  2008 al 2015 como  me  pueden ayudar

Comment: Hola Hector, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes te recomiendo que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!